# How can I convert a short[] into a int[] to create a grayscale bitmap?

Tags: android, image-processing, type-conversion

I am trying to run a denoising algorithm on a bitmap image that I have -- the function returns me a short[], so I tried simply casting it to int[] in order to generate a bitmap and I get this:

[image: http://i.min.us/ickyY6.png, android screenshot with "denoised" brain image in pink, not grayscale]

I'd like it to be in grayscale, not .. well.. pink. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pixels of a bitmap are encoded using either ARGB_8888, RGB_565, ARGB_4444, or ALPHA_8. So, the short values that you're returning must happen to correspond to values that look slightly pink-ish in one of those formats.

If you want a grayscale bitmap, you can only have values in the range of 0-256 (For the maximum precious color component of 8 bits if you're using ARGB_8888). So, you'll need to map your short to values within that range, and then replicate that value for each of the RGB components.

Comment: I'm at a loss.. I believe my values are within a 12 bit range, but I'm not certain how to get a nice grayscale -- I tried normalizing with 0xfff and then casting to int*256, but this just makes everything yellow. I'm also pretty certain this bitmap is ARGB, however I don't know much more than that.

Comment: Ok, normalize the 12 bit value to an 8 bit value by taking the upper 8 bits: `val = 0xFF & (val >> 4)` then replicate that 8 bit value in each RGB position, and just set A to 255, so: `0xFF000000 + (val << 16) + (val << 8) + val`

Comment: I'd use the bit-wise `or` operator (`|`) instead of `+`. `0XFF000000` is a negative number, which won't add correctly with the RGB components.

Comment: Your method is correct. I think I've got some other type conversion issues I need to deal with further up the line prior to this step. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replicating the 8-bit intensity in each of the RGB channels, you can use the intensity as the alpha channel. In this scheme, 0 corresponds to transparent (background color) and 255 corresponds to fully opaque (black, or whatever color you want--even pink). The idea is similar to Jason LeBrun's proposal: take the high-order 8 bits of each value, shift 24 bits left, then bitwise-OR with the color you want to use for full intensity (or with nothing, if you want black to represent full intensity).

Comment: Yeah, the benefit to this is that you can just use the ALPHA_8 BitmapConfig, too, which will reduce memory requirements for the bitmap.

Comment: I'm going to try this once I've figured out what other bug I haven't even uncovered yet -- I think I had some type conversion problems earlier up in the code from float to short and back, so we'll see. Thanks.